# как в матлабе найти качественную и количественною оценку эквализации гистограммы

Tags: matlab, обработка-изображений

Не могу найти как после эквализации гистограммы оценить коррекцию - количественною в процентах и качественно на основе разностного изображения. Смотрел в офф докемунтации матлаба и в Цифровой обработке Р.Гонсалес

Как я понял качественна оценка считаеться по формуле СКО(среднеквадратическое отклонение)
А вот количественную оценку так и не нашел

Comment: а что вы не можете запрограммировать?

Comment: @PavelGridin не могу количественную оценку